# Using the link command to keep backups on another drive

Tags: linux, backup, ln

I have a folder that contains a not so large amount of space called `/data/backup`.

I have been told that if I link that folder (`/data/backup`) to an even bigger folder area like `/bigdata/backup` for example, that I will be able to execute backups to the `/data/backup` folder.

It will then just create a link, but the data will be seen in both folders and the latter one (`/bigdata/backup`) will contain the backup results but it will show on both folders.

Since the `/bigdata/backup` has far more disk space then the backup will no longer fail because of space problems in the `/data/backup` one.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true! To use `/bigdata/backup` as if it was `/data/backup` you can use these commands in a terminal.

First, as you already have a `/data/backup` directory, move everything in it to `/bigdata/backup`:

```
mv /data/backup/* /bigdata/backup
```

Then delete your old directory:

```
rm -r /data/backup
```

Now you can link the directories with:

```
ln -s /bigdata/backup /data/backup
```

This way, `/data/backup` is essentially just a redirect to `/bigdata/backup`; it's space on disk is negligible.

Comment: Instead of `rm -r /data/backup`, I'd suggest `rmdir /data/backup`, just in case something went wrong in the `mv` step, like forgetting some important dotfiles. `rmdir` will refuse to work if there is anything left in `/data/backup`, which is probably what you want.